# IllegalStateException: in DatabaseHelper file

Tags: android, android-sqlite

Following link contains gist for the file in which I am getting the exceptions. I am getting exceptions at lines 29 and 66.

https://gist.github.com/ShashwathKumar/e1b26e8d4f6956c2afd4

Comment: And what are the exceptions !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `try-catch` in both places.

```
public void insertContact(contacts c){
    try{
       db = this.getWritableDatabase();
       ContentValues Values = new ContentValues();

       String query = "SELECT * FROM CONTACTS";
       Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
       int count = cursor.getCount();

       Values.put(COLUMN_ID, count);
       Values.put(COLUMN_NAME, c.getName());
       Values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, c.getEmail());
       Values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, c.getPassword());

       db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, Values);
       db.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
       System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Use `try-catch` for the other method also.

Answer (score 0):

### Write your create table query

```
public static final String query_create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + DatabaseHelper.TABLENAME
        + "("
        + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement ,"
        + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME
        + " text not null ,"
        + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_EMAIL
        + " text not null ,"
        + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_PASSWORD + " text not null" + ");";
```